# In C++, is it possible to use a string literal as a macro name?

Tags: c++, string, token, c-preprocessor

Here's my scenario: I have a set of source files that I'd prefer to not modify, but I'd like to replace some of the string literals with other values.  Here's an example:

```
#define "oldString" "newString"
```

Comment: **If** that worked, the result would be identical in every way to what you'd get if you just modified the source code directly. Put the source in version control so you can keep track of what changes you've made. Or write a script that massages the source prior to each compilation. Since you're compiling the source (rather than just looking at it for reference while debugging, say), there should be no danger in you modifying it in the way you've described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible. If you had already used macros in place of the strings, it would have been simple to change the macro definition to use a different string -- better late than never, you might want to do it now.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick reply.  In this case, the source files are produced by another company, and change fairly frequently, so I was hoping to just drop their files in (and do a quick diff to make sure nothing important had changed) and include this file.  My backup plan is to write a script to do the string replacement, as Rob K. suggested above.

Answer (score 5):

No, `#define` allows you to give a value to an identifier.  Identifiers can't contain the quote character.